# PHP array_push() get index?

Tags: php, arrays, key, array-push

I'm looking for a way to push values into an array with automatic incremented keys. The porblem: I want to know the key of the inserted value.

Is there a way to do this? Insert values into an array and get the index of the inserted value?

The count of the array is not equal to the next insert-key, when an item gets removed from the array.

Thanks
Alex

Comment: Nope. If I unset a value in the array, the count doesn't match with the next insert-key.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `end()` just after array_push. You will get the last insterted element.

end() advances array 's internal pointer to the last element, and returns its value.

key() returns the index element of the current array position.

Please have a look at below example:

```
$array = array(
    '0' => 'one',
    '1' => 'two',
    '2' => 'three', 
);

end($array);         // move the pointer to the end of array
$key = key($array);  // fetches the key of the element by the pointer

var_dump($key);
```

You can try one more solution, that will be faster.

```
$last_key = key( array_slice( $array, -1, 1, TRUE ) );
echo $last_key; //output "last"
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

A simple wrapper function around `array_push()` could help:

```
function array_push_autoinc(array &$array, $item) {
    $next = sizeof($array);
    $array[$next] = $item;
    return $next;
}
```

Comment: In a CLI project I used this:

$timers = array();

function addTimer($seconds){
 static $c = -1; global $timers;
 $timers[ ++$c ]=$seconds;
 return $c;
}

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

This is my **example-array**:

```
$array = [2 => "two", 1 => "one", "four" => 4];
```

As you can see, there are strings and integers used as array-keys.

First of all I need to **sort** the array by its **keys**:

```
ksort($array);
```

Now the array looks like this:

```
$array = ["four" => 4, 1 => "one", 2 => "two"];
```

Now I can **move the pointer to the end** of the array and **get the key** (so I have the highest numeric key):

```
end($array);
$key = key($array);
```

I now **increase the key by 1** and insert the value with the new key:

```
$key++;
$array[$key] = "three";
```

Now **the key is saved** in the variable `$key` and the array looks like this:

```
$array = ["four" => 4, 1 => "one", 2 => "two", 3 => "three"];
$key = 3;
```

That's it.

*Now the complete code for all of you script-kiddies out there:*

```
$array = [2 => "two", 1 => "one", "four" => 4];

ksort($array);
end($array);
$key = key($array);
$key++;

$array[$key] = "three";
```